# Will adb work on a tablet host USB port?

Tags: android, usb, adb

I want to develop on an unrooted android tablet that has both an OTG and Host USB. The Android Version is 2.3.0 so there are no Java api's to write directly to the USB host. The android device has to be attached to a computer using the OTG port so I need to connect the android host port to hardware I am designing (FTDI V2 in USB device mode). It seems the only way to communicate is using the adb to send commands from the Android tablet host port to my hardware slave port. My question is, is it possible to use the adb to communicate over the Android tablet host port, or will the adb only work on the Android tablets OTG USB port?

Any assistance appreciated....

David

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to ADB on an Android device via WiFi. This would free up the OTG port.
See https://market.android.com/details?id=siir.es.adbWireless&hl=en

Comment: Thanks for getting back. The hardware I am connecting to does not have WiFi. It only has a USB device port therefore I need to connect using the Tablets Host port.

Comment: Hmm, too bad. If it's not working on your device already, I suspect there's no way to connect ADB without the OTG port. It might be possible if you could root your device and run an ADB client on a different USB port. But that would require a bit of playing around to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

If u have a rooted device u can run the Linux binary with proper ownership, permission, and mode provisioning to the executable. Then you'd just hook up the OTG and use it as a client host. BE SURE ADBD IS RUNNING on server/target device.

You cannot use the OTG on the server side (target device) since the OTG represents the Host Control Interface and is specificly backwards to what you have set up...at least, that's the way it sounded.

In short, reverse the ports (if same type) to put OTG & HCI on the client side.